# How can i configure my wpa_supplicant.conf?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-bridge, wpa2-psk, wpa-supplicant

How can i configure my wpa_supplicant.conf?
I am using OpenWRT in my TP-link WR841N in mode STA. But I can not connect to SMC !
**I want connect to SMC by wpa_supplicant! But I know it's possible in other configuration.** My final objective is connect to eduroam (corporate, school, etc networks look like)

```
wlan0     Scan completed :
      Cell 01 - Address: 00:13:F7:E4:E3:B7
                Channel:6
                Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                Quality=37/70  Signal level=-73 dBm
                Encryption key:on
                ESSID:"SMC"
                Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                          12 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s
                Bit Rates:9 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                Mode:Master
                Extra:tsf=0000000e397f7181
                Extra: Last beacon: 100ms ago
                IE: Unknown: 0003534D43
                IE: Unknown: 010882848B960C183048
                IE: Unknown: 030106
                IE: Unknown: 07064E4C20010D14
                IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                IE: Unknown: 32041224606C
                IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                    Group Cipher : TKIP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                   Preauthentication Supported
                IE: WPA Version 1
                    Group Cipher : TKIP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (2) : TKIP CCMP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK


//My wpa_supplicant.conf

ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
ctrl_interface_group=0

network={
    ssid="SMC"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    proto=RSN
    pairwise=TKIP
    group=TKIP
    psk="secret passphrase"
}

//And in my /etc/config/wireless

config 'wifi-device' 'radio0'
    option 'type' 'mac80211'
    option 'macaddr' 'f8:d1:11:51:0a:2a'
    option 'hwmode' '11ng'
    option 'htmode' 'HT20'
    list 'ht_capab' 'SHORT-GI-20'
    list 'ht_capab' 'SHORT-GI-40'
    list 'ht_capab' 'TX-STBC'
    list 'ht_capab' 'RX-STBC1'
    list 'ht_capab' 'DSSS_CCK-40'
    option 'disabled' '0'
    option 'channel' '6'  #it is correct !

    config 'wifi-iface'
           option 'device' 'radio0'
           option 'network' 'wwan'
           option 'mode' 'sta'
           option 'ssid' 'SMC' 
           option 'encryption' 'none' #I don't if it's correct ?
```

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

in wpa_supplican.conf, write as below. remove all....

```
network={
ssid="SMC"
key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
proto=RSN
pairwise=CCMP
group=TKIP
psk="secret passphrase"
}
```

use wpa_passphrase for psk generation. You will get one kill. put **psk="that key"**

Then run with this command

```
wpa_supplicant -Dwext -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf -dd
```

change driver and interface name, if it is different.